# Convert mysql regex to java regex (and/or vice versa)

Tags: java, mysql, regex

I have some regex that I need to convert from mysql to java, but they don't work when passed to String.matches().

How do I convert a mysql regex to a java regex?
Is there any APIs (built-in or third-party) to do this?

Comment: Man ! It would be mandatory for you to post your attempts (precisely concise code snippets).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really simple. Here's the difference:

- Java's [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) needs to match the *whole* String
- mysql's [`regexp`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) only needs to match *part* of the string

To convert a mysql regex into a java one, basically add `".*"` to each end of the regex, or otherwise convert it from a "partial" match to a full match.

Here's some examples to demonstrate:

#### Java

```
"xyz".matches("y"); // false - only matches part of the input
"xyz".matches(".*y.*"); // true
"xyz".matches("[xyz]"); // false - only matches one char, but String is 3 chars
"xyz".matches("[xyz]+"); // true
```

#### mysql

```
select 'xyz' regexp 'y'; -- 1 (ie true)
select 'xyz' regexp '.*y.*'; -- 1 (ie true)
select 'xyz' regexp '[xyz]'; -- 1 (ie true)
select 'xyz' regexp '[xyz]+'; -- 1 (ie true)
```